# Angular - Choose Between Multiple Global Styles

Tags: angular

My application contains different dashboards provided by a 3rd party company.

All the SASS files are named the same and the styles use the same naming convention.

I was wondering if there's a way to load specific assets for each dashboard instead of rewriting the themes for each dashboard.

angular.json:

```
   "styles": [
          "src/styles-dashboard-1.scss",
          "src/styles-dashboard-2.scss",
          "src/styles-dashboard-3.scss",
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
          "./src/assets/js/main.js"
        ]
```

So, the folder:

> src/app/dashboard-1/dashboard-1-component

Should apply: styles-dashboard-1.scss and ignore the other styles and vice versa.

Is there a way to achieve this using Angular?